# Как сделать спец. прогу или приложение для вставки изображения с нужного пикселя автоматически?

Tags: java

Задача: посмотреть, как будут смотреться изображения одинакового или разного размера вместе, если их вставлять один под другой так, чтобы край верхнего изображения выходил за пределы конечного пикселя нижнего изображения? Это можно сделать вручную в графическом редакторе, но хочу посмотреть на все варианты такого сочетания изображений, а если у, допустим, одинаковых по размерам изображений 500 пикселей в ширину, значит мне нужно посмотреть на 500 вариантов. Вручную в графическом редакторе я бы делал это очень долго, а задача стоит сделать приложение, которое бы автоматически мне всё вставило как нужно, отрендерило все 500 изображений. А моя задача после только смотреть на них и выбирать лучший.[image: Пример одного из изображений]
Я не программист, и мне нужна инфо о том, реализуемо ли создать такое приложение или такую программу, на каком языке программирования это делается, а может быть можно сделать бота, который будет делать в графическом редакторе за меня все заданные действия.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.